# Blender screws up materials somehow

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

Okay, I have this problem...i am running blenders latest version on a MacBook Pro. I have been working on this project for the last few days and I went to start up blender today and all the material textures are screwing up and turning into this odd color-coded mess material over everything that I previously placed a realistic texture...

Any ideas i would love to here, thanks.[image]

Comment: I found that it has something to do with the Denoiser... if i have it on it does this, when i switch it off and continue to render there is no glitch... but because I'm on a potato of a mac i really need the denoiser to save my life here... It's just a bug i think.

Comment: Yeah probably a bug. Seems pretty significant though, I would report it.

Comment: so the denoiser is affecting the viewport?

Comment: Leo, yeah ha ha.. Thanks, it is a bug and hopefully shall be fixed in the next update as ther denoiser is still in alpha stage... Thanks!

Comment: David, Yes the Denoiser is affecting the Material and renderd view port of Blender. Even once i have final renderd it will still appear. Hopefully they fix this.